# how can i add a time converter in my giveaway command? eg. 1s = 1, 1h = 3600;

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i want to add a time converter in my giveaway command
.
For example if someone enters 1s then it will be 1 second
and if someone enters 1 day then it will be 86400 seconds

Any type of help will be appreciated.

my code:-

```
@client.command(description="Starts a giveaway.")
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def gstart(ctx, mins: int, *, prize: str):
    global users, new_msg
    try:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        em = discord.Embed(
            title=f"<a:fun:1052215771738165269> {prize} <a:fun:1052215771738165269>",
            color=discord.Colour.random()
        )
        # end = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=mins *60)
        timestamp = time.time() + mins
        em.set_footer(text=f"Started by {ctx.author}")
        em.add_field(name=f"** **", value=f"**Ends at**: <t:{int(timestamp)}:f> or <t:{int(timestamp)}:R> \n **Prize**: {prize} \n **Hosted by**: {ctx.author.mention}", inline=False)
        my_msg = await ctx.send(embed=em)
        await my_msg.add_reaction("")
        await asyncio.sleep(mins * 60)
        new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)
        users = [user async for user in new_msg.reactions[0].users()]
        users.pop(users.index(client.user))
        winner = random.choice(users)
        await ctx.send(f'Congratulations {winner.mention} won **{prize}**! Hosted by {ctx.author.mention}')
    except Exception as er:
        await ctx.send(er)
```

It only works in minutes right now. Any type of help will be appreciated!
if you need some more information you can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to split the user input into the number part and the "time unit" part. Define a map of all valid time units and their multiplier for the conversion in seconds, e.g.:

```
("seconds", 1), ("minutes": 60), ("hours": 3600), ("day":86400), ...
```

and then look up the inputted time unit in this map and multply the number part with the value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably to use a few Regexes.
A few example regexes would be

- Seconds: `(\d+) *(seconds|s)$`
- Minutes: `(\d+) *(minutes|mins|min|m)$`
- Hours: `(\d+) *(days|d)$`
- Extend for days etc.

Regex explained:
`(\d+)` matches any integer and puts it in a capture group
 `*` matches 0 - n whitespaces
`(seconds|s)` matches either the word `"seconds"` or `"s"` and puts it in a capture group.

All you need to do is to check if the users input like `1 hour` matches one of these regexes using pythons regex module. You can then use the capture groups to extract the number (in this case `1`) and convert it to seconds. ( `* 86.400` for hours -> seconds).